# Ignore MKUserLocation selection to register UILongTapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm looking to create a 'long hold' pin drop on an MKMapView.

Currently, everything works to the way I want it, when you tap and hold on the Map, it registers the gesture and the code drops a pin.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
}

-(void)handleLongPressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || sender == nil)
    {
        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];
        
        CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord;
        locCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
        
        //Drop Pin
    }
}
```

That is, however, it only works if you are not too close to the MKUserLocation annotation (the Blue pulsing dot) otherwise the gesture does not get registered, and the `didSelectAnnotationView:` function gets called.

Is there a way to Ignore the user taping the `MKUserLocation` annotation? I was looking for something like `setUserEnabled` but it doesn't exist for MKAnnotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MKAnnotationView` class has an `enabled` property (not the `id<MKAnnotation>` objects).

To set `enabled` on the map view's user location annotation view, get a reference to it in the `mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:` delegate method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView viewForAnnotation:mapView.userLocation];
    av.enabled = NO;  //disable touch on user location
}
```

(In `viewForAnnotation`, you have to return `nil` to tell the map view to create the view itself so `enabled` can't be set there -- at least for the user location.)